# Finding the singular homology of the quotient of the disjoint union of two spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let us consider the quotient of the disjoint union of the spaces; $D^{2}$, the two dimensional disc, and $M$, the Mobius strip with the equivalence relation that identifies the boundary of $D^{2}$ and $M$.In other words $D^{2} \bigsqcup M / \sim $.

I would like to compute the singular homology of this quotient.

I know that homology is homotopic invariant and hence it follows that it is invariant under homeomorphism, and so I need to find a space which is homeomorphic to this of which I known the homology.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963241/how-to-see-the-real-projective-plane-is-a-m%C3%B6bius-band-glued-to-a-disk This shows that the space you are looking for is $\mathbb R P^2$.

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963241/how-to-see-the-real-projective-plane-is-a-m%C3%B6bius-band-glued-to-a-disk) should answer your question.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helps