# Compact, connected 2-manifold is a connected sum of another manifold and $P^2$ under some condition

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

A question from *Introduction to topological manifold* exercise 5-4

Exe5.4: Suppose M is a compact, connected 2-manifold that contains a subset $B\subset M$  that is homeomorphic to the Möbius band. Show that there is a compact 2-manifold M' such that M is homeomorphic to a connected sum $M'$#$P^2$.

I know if M is a compact, connected 2-manifold, then M has a very good **surface presentation**. But I have no geometric intuition on the question and can't figure out how to rigorously apply the surface presentation.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is given by gluing a unit ball along the boundary of a mobius band (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963241/how-to-see-the-real-projective-plane-is-a-m%C3%B6bius-band-glued-to-a-disk)).